# Android, Bunch of imagebuttons

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton

I am a learning via a book so please forgive this newbie question.

I have a bunch of imageButtons in my xml, here is how one of them looks:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/level1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:onClick="button_clicked1"></ImageButton>
```

and processing code:

```
public void button_clicked1(View v) {
    text1.setText("clicked");

    }
```

rather than have each button have its separate onClick code, is there anyway I can pass which button was clicked? for example `button_clicked(1)` and then `button_clicked(2)` instead of `button_clicked1` like it is now (in the above example xml code)

or i have no choice but have to do it separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of - what I like to do is make my View or Activity implement View.OnClickListener.

```
public class MyView extends ImageButton implements OnClickListener
```

Then during onCreate, I do something like:

```
((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1)).setOnClickListener(this);
```

then, in my onclick:

```
public void onClick(View view){
 switch(view.getId()){
   case R.id.imageButton1:
      // do something.
      break;
   case R.id.imageButton2:
      // do somethign else.
      break;
 }
```

Of course, you can definitely get creative and toss the switch statement if any of your buttons should trigger the same event behavior.  Also, I'm not in a place where I can easily view my droid references so there may be an OnClickListener specific to ImageButton - if so, implement that on your containing View or Activity to consolidate the handlers...

Hope that makes sense - happy coding!

B

Comment: Yeah, I also think this is the best choice.

Comment: That means I will instead have to have a bunch of `((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1)).setOnClickListener(this);` code instead, right?

Comment: Quite unforuntately, yes.  I'm unaware of any other way (declaratively, for example) to assign handlers.